# Unreadable calendar event's in Dark Mode

Tags: calendar

Calendar with dark mode it's almost impossible to use. Colors for event's make unreadable information without access the event itself.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## **Hello!**

I was able to resolve this issue by downloading the application source code from the official repository on GitHub *(you can find it [here](https://github.com/elementary/calendar))*, altering a line from the css file responsible for the style of events and reinstalling the application from this source.

This is how it looks now
[image]

#### Step by step

- When you download the source, extract to any location
- Open the file `/calendar-master/data/style/AgendaEventRow.css` in any text editor
- The first block of code should be:

> ```
> .event {
>     background: alpha(@accent_color, 0.15);
>     border-radius: 3px;
>     color: shade(@accent_color, 0.65);
>     padding: 6px;
> }
> ```

- You'll have to alter both the `background` and the `color` attribute

In my case I altered to this:

> ```
> .event {
>     background: alpha(@accent_color, 0.75);
>     border-radius: 3px;
>     color: shade(@accent_color, 0.35);
>     padding: 6px;
> }
> ```

But you can alter to whatever you like

- Now all you need to do is install it.

#### Following the README.md file from the source package:

- Make sure you have all the dependencies installed

> `sudo apt install libchamplain-0.12-dev libchamplain-gtk-0.12-dev libclutter-1.0-dev libecal1.2-dev libedataserverui1.2-dev libfolks-dev libgee-0.8-dev libgeocode-glib-dev libgeoclue-2-dev libglib2.0-dev libgranite-dev libgtk-3-dev libical-dev meson valac`

You can run this to install all the dependencies

With the dependencies met, you now have to compile it using meson

- In the `calendar-master` folder run
- `meson build --prefix=/usr`
- `cd build`
- `ninja`

This will compile the source code

- And finally inside the `build` folder run:
- `sudo ninja install`

*Take note that, you don't have to uninstall the current calendar in other to install it from source, however the new installation will override the current one.

*If you want to remove the colors from the background entirely, you can follow this solution from user "thomsch98" on a GitHub thread about the same issue.

You can find this solution *[here](https://github.com/elementary/calendar/issues/267)*

Comment: Pity that developers did not catch this issue.

Comment: Reported: https://github.com/elementary/calendar/issues/552